# Google Cloud Storage experiences & examples

Tags: android, rest, cloud, boto, google-cloud-storage

I want to start using Google Cloud for Tracking a few phones at the same time, for HighScore Storage eg. Small things. I´m reading on StackOverflow and on http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html#boto.
Since I don´t have any experience at all with using any external online storage in android, I was wondering if anybody could help me a bit in the right direction.

I saw that there are three ways to access and manage the cloud files:

- REST
- GSUtil
- Boto

I´m sure there are advantages and disadvantages. Anybody can explain me a bit or give me a webpage with a clear explanation and some example code and usage, so I can decide which one I want to use and to study.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST describes the communication protocol used to interact with the GS. It reuses the same HTTP commands used for serving web pages (HEAD, PUT, GET, etc.). REST is programing language agnostic and most languages should have a library for dealing with it.

boto is a Python module for interacting with a variety of private and public cloud storage solutions, including Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3.

gsutil is a Python script providing a command line interface the GS using the boto module.

If you are targeting Dalvic using Java you will need to find or write your own GS library wrapping whatever Java REST library you use. There is support for GS in the Google App Engine you might be able to 're-purpose', and I found this too: http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html.

The Python distro for SL4A will work with the boto module, and if you set up correctly the gsutil tool can be run via ConnectBot or some similar terminal application on Android.